# .ASPXAUTH cookie expires at session end

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, cookies

I use common auth infrastructure of asp.net with auth controls (login, logout, ...)

My config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Administrators/Login.aspx" timeout="500000" />
</authentication>
```

I hope see that .ASPXAUTH cookie would expires at next year and i shouldn't enter login\passw again and again

But I see that this cookie always expires at the end of the session.
How can I change this behaviour?

**EDIT**

sure I use checkox "Remember me". I think asp.net should create persistant cookie

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create persistent cookies, use:

[FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie)
```

**createPersistentCookie**: true to create a persistent cookie (one that is saved across browser sessions); otherwise, false.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a persistent cookie. If you use the default login control of ASP.NET, set the [DisplayRememberMe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.displayrememberme%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on true, then the user gets the option to remember his login and the persistent cookie will be created.

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
    DisplayRememberMe = "True">
</asp:Login>
```